# Help me identify this DC power connector

Tags: power, dc, connector

[image: photo of person holding the connector attached to cable]

[image: diagram showing the connector wiring]

This is a DC power connector used with the Ericsson Telecom Equipment. I do not have the connector physically, so I would not be able to provide the measurements.

Kindly please help if you are able to identify its name or make.

Comment: So what about the faces not shown? any printing visible?

Comment: It looks similar to the old "AMP-MODU" (nowadays by TE Connectivity), which comes in all manner of shapes and sizes. More details are needed though: pitch (likely 0.1''/2.54mm but I could be wrong?), AWG size (roughly), pictures from several angles etc.

Comment: hey, can you please assist me on how i can add more images?

Comment: @SolarMike No, there is nothing visible.

Comment: Add images of the mating connector (or PCB, if it's a PCB edge). Also, measure and report the pitch: center-to-center distance between each set of contacts.